# find duplicate subset of columns with nan values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 4 columns that can have np.nan

```
df = 
    i_example i_frame  OId  HId
0           0      20  3.0  0.0
1           3      13  NaN  8.0
2           3      13  NaN  10.0
3           0      21  3.0  NaN
4           0      21  3.0  0.0
5           1      22  0.0  4.0
6           1      22  NaN  4.0
7           2      20  0.0  4.0
8           2      20  1.0  4.0
```

I am looking for invalid rows.
invalid rows are
[1] rows with duplicate `columns = [i_example, i_frame, OId]` or
[2] rows with duplicate `columns = [i_example, i_frame, HId]`.
So in the example above, all the rows are invalid beside the first three rows.

```
valid_df = 
    i_example i_frame  OId  HId
0           0      20  3.0  0.0
1           3      13  NaN  8.0
2           3      13  NaN  10.0
```

and

```
invalid_df = 
    i_example i_frame  OId  HId
3           0      21  3.0  NaN
4           0      21  3.0  0.0
5           1      22  0.0  4.0
6           1      22  NaN  4.0
7           2      20  0.0  4.0
8           2      20  1.0  4.0
```

```
1           0      21  3.0  NaN
2           0      21  3.0  0.0
```

These two rows are invalid because of the condition [1].

and

```
3           1      22  0.0  4.0
4           1      22  NaN  4.0
```

are invalid because of the condition [2]

and

```
5           2      20  0.0  4.0
6           2      20  1.0  4.0
```

are invalid for the same reason

I tried is_duplicated but it does not work with nan values

Comment: can you share what you did with is_duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the `df.duplicated()` function offers to eliminate `NaN`s. But you can add a condition to check of the value is `NaN` or not and find the duplicates.

```
df[df.duplicated(['i_example', 'i_frame', 'OId'], keep=False) & df['OId'].notna()]
```

Result:

```
   i_example  i_frame  OId  HId
3          0       21  3.0  NaN
4          0       21  3.0  0.0
```

So, for your question, I would see if the value is not `NaN` and then find the duplicates using `df.duplicated()` and create a boolean mask. With that filter the df as valid and invalid.

```
dupes = (df['OId'].notna() & df.duplicated(['i_example', 'i_frame', 'OId'], keep=False)) | (df['HId'].notna() & df.duplicated(['i_example', 'i_frame', 'HId'], keep=False))
invalid_df = df[dupes]
valid_df = df[~dupes]
```

Result:

```
valid_df = 
   i_example  i_frame  OId   HId
0          0       20  3.0   0.0
1          3       13  NaN   8.0
2          3       13  NaN  10.0

invalid_df = 
   i_example  i_frame  OId  HId
3          0       21  3.0  NaN
4          0       21  3.0  0.0
5          1       22  0.0  4.0
6          1       22  NaN  4.0
7          2       20  0.0  4.0
8          2       20  1.0  4.0
```